# How to move NetBeans Workspace?

Tags: netbeans, ide, netbeans-6.9

I have installed NetBeans in C drive and now I want to move it to another drive.

Is there any option available in NetBeans?

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling.

Comment: I want to move the workspace without uninstalling

Comment: See if there's a setup variable that gives the path to the default workspace directory.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is the option of project group.

> File > Project group.

Here you can create a project group based on a folder location.

Then you can switch between projects within selected group.

Switching between project groups doesn't require closing the IDE.

It look like Workspace for Eclipse.

Hope it will help!

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click on your project
2. In the context menu, select "Move..." option
3. Choose the location you want to move your project to

Answer (score 1):

You want to copy the so called "userdir".

For details, please refer to the FAQ:

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir

http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansUserFAQ#Configuration

Answer (score 1):

I am using NetBeans 8.0.2 on Windows 7.

The projects in my workspace are also in a "Project Group" by root directory for a suite of projects. (What Eclipse would call a "workspace" for all projects, or a "Working Set" for a subset of projects.)

In `C:\Users\<myname>\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\projectui\groups\<mygroup>.properties` is listed the path to the group of projects.

In Explorer, move (: or copy if you are paranoid enough :) your workspace directories to the new drive.

Edit this file and change the drive location for the group.

NetBeans will now see the new location when it opens and loads the workspace and groups.

Use `File / Project Groups ...` to ensure you are looking at the group you think you are looking at.